# Kolmogorov complexity of $n$

Tags: probability

I was reading a paper on Kolmogorov complexity, but got stuck on the convergence part. It states that a common form to assign probability to integers $n$ would be $P(n)=A2^{-\log_2^*n}$, where $\log_2^*n=\log_2n+\log_2\log_2n+\beta \log_2\log_2\log_2n$, and $A$ some constant. To make sense, I want to know why $\sum 2^{-\log_2^*n}$ converges, for all $\beta > 1$. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the integral test,

$$
\sum_n2^{-\log_2^*n}=\sum_n\frac1{n\log_2n(\log_2\log_2n)^\beta}
$$

converges because the summand decreases with $n$ and

$$
\int_4^x\mathrm dn\frac1{n\log_2n(\log_2\log_2n)^\beta}=\frac{\log^22}{1-\beta}\left((\log_2\log_2x)^{1-\beta}-1\right)
$$

converges for $x\to\infty$.